# Which kind of database and chat library is good for chat based application using Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, couchdb, chat

I am trying to build a chat-based application which is similar to Whatsapp. 
Using the database like Couch Database and socket.io chat library to build chat based application...

The problems which I am facing are:

1. Messages are getting delayed when I am trying to see old messages in the one-one chat window or group chat window
2. When I try to send a message from one device to another (ie one user to another user, it is taking huge time to deliver the message or smileys)
3. Fetching old chat histories are very bad
4. Sending messages through socket is not getting triggered immediately
5. unable to see images once I click 'send button' - taking huge time to see image preview and once after it has sent

vi) Once I create a group, to display it in the listview, it's taking more time

My Question here is:

Which chat library should I use instead of socket.io to send messages like WhatsApp chat

Which database should I use instead of using couch DB?

I have researched a lot about Redis, Couch DB and Mnesia Db
and pusher, pubnub, chat sdk etc..

Please, could anyone suggest me which one should I go for chat application (fast delivered messages with reliable, efficient, message storing and fetching and showing messages even in offline)?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using PubNub's opinionated JavaScript framework called [ChatEngine](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started?devrel_so=which-kind-of-database-and-chat). It takes away a lot of the heavy lifting involved with making chat with PubNub. It has plugins for emojis, typing indicator, markdown, and more.

The message delivery SLA is <250ms globally.

Here is some example code to get you started making 1:1 private chats in JavaScript. Make sure you use the [ChatEngine setup button](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started?devrel_so=which-kind-of-database-and-chat#automagic-pubnub-setup) to prepare the backend on your account.

```
import ChatEngineCore from 'chat-engine';

// Init ChatEngine with PubNub
const publishKey = '__Your_PubNub_Publish_Key__';
const subscribeKey = '__Your_PubNub_Subscribe_Key__';

const ChatEngine = ChatEngineCore.create({
  publishKey,
  subscribeKey,
}, {
  globalChannel: 'global',
});

const user = {
    uuid: 'randomstringofchars',
    name: 'John Smith'
}

const chats = {};

ChatEngine.connect(user.uuid, user);

ChatEngine.on('$.ready', function(data) {

    // store my new user as `me`
    let me = data.me;

    // returns a ChatEngine chat object
    function makePrivateChat(theirUserId) {
        const chatKey = [theirUserId, me.uuid].sort().join('-');

        // Don't make the same 1:1 chat if it already exists
        if (chats[chatKey]) {
            return;
        }

        // true for private chat
        const chat = new ChatEngine.Chat(chatKey, true);

        chats[chatKey] = chat;
    }

    // Auto add a 1:1 chat to UI when invited by someone
    me.direct.on('$.invite', makePrivateChat);

    // Define a button for making new 1:1 chats in your UI
    newOneToOneChatButton.on('click', function (event, theirUserId) {
        someChatObject.invite(theirUserId);
    });
});
```